# Angular Json Schema Form change titleMap dynamically based on falue from another select field

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, jsonschema

Is there any way to change/filter titleMap in form dynamically based on value from another field inserted by user? In my schema i've 2 select fields (I anonymize values):

```
{ "key": "form.category", "flex": "3 3 150px",
          "notitle": false, "type": "select", "titleMap": [
        {"name": "1", "value": "1"},
        {"name": "2", "value": "2"},
        {"name": "3", "value": "3"},
        {"name": "4", "value": "4"},
        {"name": "5", "value": "5"},
        {"name": "6", "value": "6"},
        {"name": "7", "value": "7"},
        {"name": "8", "value": "8"},
        {"name": "9", "value": "9"}
      ]
        },
```

and second:

```
 { "key": "form.subcategory", "flex": "1 1 150px",
          "notitle": false, "type": "select", "titleMap": [
        { "group": "1", "name": "A", "value": "A" },
        { "group": "1", "name": "B", "value": "B" },
        { "group": "1", "name": "C", "value": "C"},
        { "group": "2", "name": "D", "value": "D"},
        { "group": "2", "name": "E", "value": "E"},
        { "group": "2", "name": "F", "value": "F"},
        { "group": "2", "name": "G", "value": "G"},
        { "group": "3", "name": "H", "value": "H"},
        { "group": "3", "name": "I", "value": "I"},
        { "group": "3", "name": "J", "value": "J"},
        { "group": "4", "name": "K", "value": "K"},
        { "group": "5", "name": "L", "value": "L"},
        { "group": "5", "name": "M", "value": "M"},
        { "group": "5", "name": "N", "value": "N"},
        {"group": "6", "name": "O", "value": "O"}
      ]
        }
```

I load schema and if user chose 1 from category i would like in subcategory create dropdown where group is = 1, if user in category chose 2 - dropdown in subcategory should have only values where group is 2 etc.

I tried to do this by dynamic select in onChanges() but it doesn't work:

```
onChanges(changes: any) {
    this.liveFormData = changes;
    this.zmienna = this.liveFormData.form.category;
    this.jsonFormObject.form[2].items[1]['titleMap'].filter(obj => obj['group'] == this.zmienna); // position of my subcategory

  }
```

or

```
onChanges(changes: any) {
    this.liveFormData = changes;
    this.zmienna = this.liveFormData.form.category;
    this.dane = this.jsonFormObject.form[2].items[1]['titleMap'].filter(obj => obj['group'] == this.zmienna); //   position of my subcategory
    this.jsonFormObject.form[2].items[1]['titleMap'].length = 0;
    this.jsonFormObject.form[2].items[1]['titleMap'] = this.dane;
  }
```

my html:

```
<json-schema-form *ngIf="formActive" loadExternalAssets="false" [form]="jsonFormObject"
        [options]="jsonFormOptions" [(data)]="submittedFormData" [framework]="selectedFramework"
        [language]="selectedLanguage" (onChanges)="onChanges($event)" (onSubmit)="onSubmit($event)"
        (isValid)="isValid($event)" (validationErrors)="validationErrors($event)">
      </json-schema-form>
```

Is there any way to dynamic change values in second dropdown? Maybe during schema loading?

Comment: Same issue here, if you've achieved any solution I would apreciate if you share it.